# Why inline cache is faster than dictionary mode in v8

Tags: javascript, v8

I have read https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/06/03/explaining-js-vms-in-js-inline-caches.html. When accessing the property of object, `inline-cache` will need a hash of `property name` to lookup for the cached stub to get the offset. And in `dictionary mode`, look up will only need a hash too. Why `inline cache` is 6x faster than `dictionary mode`?

Comment: The inline cache is available right there - *inline*. The dictionary mode lookup will need to lookup the hash in a dictionary (traverse a data structure!) stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's quite the interpretation of it.

The entire point of the inline cache is to "fast-track" the retrieval process for specific properties. The way he proposes this (and the way that it's done in V8) is to create hidden classes behind the scenes for our objects.

So a basic object like this

```
const obj = {
    foo: 1
}
```

will be backed by a hidden class, something like:

```
class A {
    foo: number
}
```

If you create a new object, `obj2` with the same format, so that

```
const obj2 = {
    foo: 5
}
```

it'll be backed by the same `A` class.

If we add a new property to `obj2`:

```
const obj2 = {
    foo: 5,
    bar: 10
}
```

then it'll get backed by a different class - either to a class that already exists (if we have one of the same format), or to a new one:

```
class B {
    foo: number,
    bar: number
}
```

There's a lot more to it, but that's the gist of it.

This means that whenever you do something like `obj.foo` in your code, the compiler can fast-track that retrieval using inline caching - it *knows* that the property `foo` exists, and that it's of type `number`.

If you're doing a hash map lookup (i.e. pure `Object` properties) where your property might not exist (e.g. `obj["baz"]`), then it can no longer fast track that process, and has to check to see if `baz` exists, then gets it etc

For the majority of code, even the slower method is "fast enough" - unless you're doing like he's doing and running a 100k loop.

In short, inline caching is faster because it can skip a load of internal checks and casting etc - it just returns the variable

More info on this in V8: https://richardartoul.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/04/26/hidden-classes.html
https://engineering.linecorp.com/en/blog/v8-hidden-class/

Comment: Thanks for the answer and info link. I maybe get it now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The "inline cache" approach has two stages: *configuring* the inline cache and *executing* the inline cache.

You're right that *configuring* (a.k.a. "patching") the inline cache needs to hash the property key. In fact, this is typically significantly slower than a plain and simple dictionary-based approach. But it only needs to be done very infrequently (in the example program, only once per IC)!

The configured inline cache then gets *executed* repeatedly (in the example, 100,000 times), and every time all it does is executing the following function:

```
function KeyedLoadFastProperty(t, k, ic) {
  if (t.klass !== klass) {
    // Expected klass does not match. Can't use cached index.
    // Fall through to the runtime system.
    return NAMED_LOAD_MISS(t, k, ic);
  }
  return t.properties[index];
}
```

which, as you can see, does not need to hash anything (assuming `t.klass` is the same as what it was before, when the IC was patched); it does a simple index-based load from an array, which is super fast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I originally think inline cache will need a hash to look up the `LOAD${id}` function, but I didn't consider a hash will need to look up `load` function in the table too. Thus, I originally think a hash will need to look up the `LOAD${id}` function in the inline cache way and a hash will need to look up the property value in the map way. Now, I get it that inline cache can save the query time in map through the index based load. Thanks again!